# Echo statement not coming out as i want it

Tags: php

This code only prints out '17' instead of "10 +  7 = 17". Why is this? And how can i solve this.

```
<?

$x = 10;
$y = 7;

echo $x . '+' . $y . '=' . $x+$y;

?>
```

Comment: @IMSoP Oh, I see -- you're right. Removed noise.

Answer (score 11):

What you should understand is that `echo` won't do anything until the result of the whole expression given to it is evaluated. This expression contains both `.` and `+` *operators* - the first one concatenates its operands (glues two strings together), the second adds numbers.

Now, you might think that `+` operator has a higher precedence than of `.` one - in other words, that result of `$x + $y` will be calculated before (eventually) glued to the rest of the string. But it's not. So we can say this statement is actually treated as...

```
echo ($x . '+' . $y . '=' . $x) + $y;
```

In other words, the *result* of all the string concatenation is added (converted to number) to $y, and only the result of this operation is printed.

The result of `$x . '+' . $y . '=' . $x` is `'10+7=10'`, and it doesn't look like something that might be *added*. But guess what, PHP wants to be nice to you - and it assumes that you actually wanted to extract the first digits of a string when you tried to convert it to a number. So the whole line is treated as number `10`. When added to `7`, it's just 17 - that's why you got 17 echoed.

One possible workaround is getting rid of `.`, using `,` operator instead (as its precedence is lower - in fact, it's the [lowest among operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)):

```
echo $x, '+', $y, '=', $x + $y;
```

It could be simplified if one remember about such a handy feature of PHP as string interpolation:

```
echo "$x + $y = ", $x + $y;
```

Comment: This made me more confuse. Can you please explain more.

Comment: Very well explained :D But OP doesn't seems to understand, maybe you can provide him a link to the priorities  of operators

Comment: But i put the + sign in quotes. So why did it get treated differently.

Comment: @TenkorangDarko The `+` sign that's the problem is the one at the end, that actually adds up the numbers, not the one in quotes.

Comment: Thats what i intended it to do. But for some reason, that seems to not print out the statement before it. "10+7=17". The echo statement just prints "17" and ignores the rest. @IMSoP

Comment: @TenkorangDarko Please read through raina77ow's answer carefully; it's been expanded with a lot of explanation of how PHP reads your code, and why that doesn't match your expectations.

Comment: echo prints the *result* of the whole expression - and it's evaluated left-to-right. The last operator is `+` - an arithmetical addition. So it takes the result of all the concatenation operatins (a string), _converts_ it to number, add to 7, and voila! you got a 17.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$x = 10;
$y = 7;
function sum($a,$b){
    return $a+$b;
}
echo $x.'+'.$y.'='.sum($x,$y);
?>
```